# How to flatten a list of dictionaries with non-constant attributes

Tags: python, json, pandas, rest, dictionary

Until recently I used the relatively simple code below to fetch location data from an API, flatten the response and convert to a flat dataframe/table.   It worked well because the key "ExtendedAttributes" returned a constant set of values and in a constant order.  The API schema changed overnight (without warning) and now different return different values based on attributes of each location.

The easier solution of flattening the nested lists of dictionaries into a table and renaming columns no longer works.   I'm not really sure how to proceed with a case like this or what approach to try first.

**Script**

```
# Fetch the initial location description list
locationDescriptions = timeseries.publish.get('/GetLocationDescriptionList')['LocationDescriptions']

#Loop through provisioning API to get full location info for every UniqueID
locations = timeseries.provisioning.send_batch_requests('/locations/{Id}', [{'LocationUniqueId': loc['UniqueId']} for loc in locationDescriptions])

#API response in 'locations' is nested JSON so we need to unpack/flatten it.  
dic_flattened = [flatten(d) for d in locations]

df_flat =pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)

#give value columns matching names
df_flat.rename(columns = {'ExtendedAttributeValues_0_Value' : 'COUNTY' ...}, inplace = true)
```

**First location**

```
 "ExtendedAttributeValues": [
{
  "ColumnIdentifier": "COUNTY@LOCATION_EXTENSION",
  "Value": "Okaloosa - FL",
  "UniqueId": "538e05b45a9a4b31a46cf96c4ffab8cb"
},
{
  "ColumnIdentifier": "GW_REGION@LOCATION_EXTENSION",
  "Value": "Western Panhandle Embayment Region",
  "UniqueId": "5f51ebde984c4bdd92dff067cbe5b39b"
},
{
  "ColumnIdentifier": "LAND_NET@LOCATION_EXTENSION",
  "Value": "S016T3NR22W",
  "UniqueId": "8d8139c9027a497f9cae4ef7471930ba"
}
```

**2nd location (attributes no longer match)**

```
"ExtendedAttributeValues": [
{
  "ColumnIdentifier": "DATA_USED@GW_EXTENSION",
  "Value": "",
  "UniqueId": "dace52af725b42a9aa63aa8e1b9a1b74"
},
{
  "ColumnIdentifier": "TOP_BUCATUNA@GW_EXTENSION",
  "Value": "",
  "UniqueId": "352e5763d90748a490b32ba833a65d1c"
},
{
  "ColumnIdentifier": "TOP_FLORIDAN@GW_EXTENSION",
  "Value": "",
  "UniqueId": "b940292e63e84214ab785584f420674b"
}
```

Flattening now results in a table like this:

| **ExtendedAttributeValues_0_Value** | **ExtendedAttributeValues_1_ColumnIdentifier** | **ExtendedAttributeValues_1_Value** | **ExtendedAttributeValues_2_ColumnIdentifier** | **ExtendedAttributeValues_2_Value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COUNTY@LOCATION_EXTENSION | Okaloosa - FL | GW_REGION@LOCATION_EXTENSION | Western Panhandle Embayment Region | LAND_NET@LOCATION_EXTENSION |
| DATA_USED@GW_EXTENSION |  | TOP_BUCATUNA@GW_EXTENSION |  | TOP_FLORIDAN@GW_EXTENSION |

But I want to turn every "ColumnIdentifier" into column name and fill the rows of that column with the associated "Value":

| **DATA_USED** | **GW_REGION** | **TOP_BUCATUNA** | **LAND_NET** | **TOP_FLORIDAN** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Okaloosa - FL |  | Western Panhandle Embayment Region |  | S016T3NR22W |

Comment: both dictionaries have the same keys, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
     "ExtendedAttributeValues": [
    {
      "ColumnIdentifier": "COUNTY@LOCATION_EXTENSION",
      "Value": "Okaloosa - FL",
      "UniqueId": "538e05b45a9a4b31a46cf96c4ffab8cb"
    },
    {
      "ColumnIdentifier": "GW_REGION@LOCATION_EXTENSION",
      "Value": "Western Panhandle Embayment Region",
      "UniqueId": "5f51ebde984c4bdd92dff067cbe5b39b"
    },
    {
      "ColumnIdentifier": "LAND_NET@LOCATION_EXTENSION",
      "Value": "S016T3NR22W",
      "UniqueId": "8d8139c9027a497f9cae4ef7471930ba"
    }
    ]
}

data2 = {
    "ExtendedAttributeValues": [
    {
      "ColumnIdentifier": "DATA_USED@GW_EXTENSION",
      "Value": "",
      "UniqueId": "dace52af725b42a9aa63aa8e1b9a1b74"
    },
    {
      "ColumnIdentifier": "TOP_BUCATUNA@GW_EXTENSION",
      "Value": "",
      "UniqueId": "352e5763d90748a490b32ba833a65d1c"
    },
    {
      "ColumnIdentifier": "TOP_FLORIDAN@GW_EXTENSION",
      "Value": "",
      "UniqueId": "b940292e63e84214ab785584f420674b"
    }
    ]
}
```

Given either dictionary, we can read them simply using `pd.json_normalize`:

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(data, 'ExtendedAttributeValues')
df2 = pd.json_normalize(data2, 'ExtendedAttributeValues')
```

Output:

- df1

```
               ColumnIdentifier                               Value                          UniqueId
0     COUNTY@LOCATION_EXTENSION                       Okaloosa - FL  538e05b45a9a4b31a46cf96c4ffab8cb
1  GW_REGION@LOCATION_EXTENSION  Western Panhandle Embayment Region  5f51ebde984c4bdd92dff067cbe5b39b
2   LAND_NET@LOCATION_EXTENSION                         S016T3NR22W  8d8139c9027a497f9cae4ef7471930ba
```

- df2

```
            ColumnIdentifier Value                          UniqueId
0     DATA_USED@GW_EXTENSION        dace52af725b42a9aa63aa8e1b9a1b74
1  TOP_BUCATUNA@GW_EXTENSION        352e5763d90748a490b32ba833a65d1c
2  TOP_FLORIDAN@GW_EXTENSION        b940292e63e84214ab785584f420674b
```

If you have a larger JSON response than this, where the old `Value` is now stored at a higher level for example, you can look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas-json-normalize) for `pd.json_normalize` for how to extract that information, or update your question with enough information to actually answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit to try and explain a little better.  The previous API returned a constant list of attributes so flattening and renaming the "Value" column as the ColumnIdentifer then dropping the columns from the dataframe was easy.  But now the attributes are variable and I'm trying to figure out how to create a flat table from that.

Comment: Sharing the complete new formatting, not just the small subsection, would be helpful for developing a solution if you're looking for help with that...